# Why does Node.js shorten my buffer when writing to file?

Tags: node.js

I'm experiencing some weird behavior in NodeJS `v14.16.1` on Windows 10.

When I append 4 bytes to a file, it's only appending 2 bytes:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

let infoFile = fs.openSync('field.info', 'a');

fs.writeSync(infoFile, Buffer.from([0x06, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00]))

fs.closeSync(infoFile);
```

Output for field.info:

```
06 04
```

Expected output:

```
06 00 04 00
```

`Buffer.from([0x06, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00])` produces the expected output:

```
06 00 04 00 00
```

The `.toString()` on the `Buffer`'s produce strings of the correct length, so I can only imagine it's an issue in `fs.writeSync`.  I can't find anything in the documentation that would indicate the issue...

*Edit*
`fs.writeSync` reports `4` bytes written but only 2 exist in the file.

Comment: Why do you think there are only two bytes in that file? Are you opening this file with a text editor? Then the editor may interpret the file as UTF-16 where each char is represented by two bytes ... Getting the file properties clearly shows the file contains 4 bytes ...

Comment: @derpirscher, I was opening the file with `notepad++`, `vscode`, and a hex editor.  All three decided `UTF-16 Little Endian` was the appropriate format.  Can you answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most certainly due to the editor you opening the file with, interpreting it as UTF-16. Thus, you see only two characters, because each character is representing two bytes. Showing the file properties in windows explorer clearly shows the correct file size.